# Child element does not inherit background color from its parent, why?

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have a nested `div` structure in my HTML, and then I apply some `background-color` in the outer div, but the inner div does not inherit that property, how can I achieve that?

```css
.some-class {
  background-color: #0b7261 !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-class">
  <div class="sub-head">
    <h1>some-text</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container f-left">
    <div id="some-text1">
      <h2>some-text</h2>
      <p class="desc-text">some-text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="some-text2">
      <h2>some-text</h2>
      <p class="desc-text">some-text </p>
    </div>
    <div id="some-text3">
      <h2>some-text</h2>
      <p class="desc-text">some-text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I simply added `background-color` to my upper div `some-class`

When I apply this, there is no background color in the container class.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what result you get?

Comment: But this is true now! as saying, Johannes.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't happen by default, in fact, in most cases the elements will be overlapping (as they are in your example) and therefore effectively have the same background anyways.

However, if you specifically want this behavior, you can use the css `inherit` keyword

```css
.some-class{
   background-color: #0b7261;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   color :white;
   padding: 10px;
}
 .container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: inherit;
  }
```

Comment: When I use this, there is a gap of 10 px around the container class background, which is probably due to padding?

Comment: I am honestly unable to replicate this behavior, I am running on chrome. The "container" should be completely transparent and show the parent background behind it, so I am unsure how you are perceiving any kind of gap

Comment: I mean there is a margin of 10px (which is white in color) on both left and right side of the container, which should also be the color I specified.

Comment: @IcanCode I understand what you're describing but don't understand why that behavior would be happening, that isn't how the CSS should work, what browser are you on? THis behavior does not appear for us.

Comment: I use firefox as my primary web browser.

Comment: @IcanCode I am unsure what white lines you are referring to, please make sure the code in your question replicates the issue

Answer (score 2):

`background-color` simply is not a property that is inherited to child elements. However in most cases, child elements will be *inside* the parent, and the default setting for `background-color` is `transparent`, so *most* child elements that don't have a background-color set will appear with the parent's background-color (coming through from the parent), as it can also be seen in the snippet which is part of your question.

For the rare situations where a child element is *outside*  the parent (or partly outside), you can use the `inherit` setting for background-color.